# Run script on Gitlab after saving wiki page

Tags: gitlab

I am new to Gitlab and make different tests with it. I have an idea for which cant find specific solution. When I create or edit wiki page for some project, I want to trigger a script. Are there any ways I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating your wiki via gitlab gui you can use [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) to trigger some job execution. Webhooks can be found in project **Settings ➔ Integrations**

If you update wiki via CLI push there is an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/13862) open for it.